# Assign the content of xaml file to App.ViewModel property?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7

I defined my complete viewmodel using XAML:

```
<local:TestViewModel xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                     xmlns:local="clr-namespace:icColors"
                     SampleProperty="Sample Text Property Value">

    <local:TestViewModel.Questions>
     ....
    </local:TestViewModel.Questions>
</local:TestViewModel>
```

How can parse this XAML at runtime and set as a property of my application, `App.TestViewModel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse XAML at runtime using the [XAMLReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.aspx) class. Simply parse your XAML using the `XamlReader.Load` method, then assign it (remembering to cast the result). Here is some example code:

```
System.Windows.Resources.StreamResourceInfo streamInfo = System.Windows.Application.GetResourceStream(uri);

if ((streamInfo != null) && (streamInfo.Stream != null))
{
    using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(streamInfo.Stream))
    {
        TestViewModel vm = System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(reader.ReadToEnd()) as TestViewModel;
    }
}
```